# Change the scalar style used for all multi-line strings when serialising a dynamic model using YamlDotNet

Tags: yaml, yamldotnet

I am using the following code snippet to serialise a dynamic model of a project to a string (which is eventually exported to a YAML file).

```cs
    dynamic exportModel = exportModelConvertor.ToDynamicModel(project);
    var serializerBuilder = new SerializerBuilder();
    var serializer = serializerBuilder.EmitDefaults().DisableAliases().Build();

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(sw, exportModel);
        string result = sw.ToString();
    }
```

Any multi-line strings such as the following:

```
propertyName = "One line of text
followed by another line
and another line"
```

are exported in the following format:

```
propertyName: >
  One line of text

  followed by another line

  and another line
```

Note the extra (unwanted) line breaks.

According to this [YAML Multiline guide](https://yaml-multiline.info/), the format used here is the folded block scalar style. Is there a way using YamlDotNet to change the style of this output for all multi-line string properties to literal block scalar style or one of the flow scalar styles?

The [YamlDotNet documentation](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Serialization.Serializer) shows how to apply ScalarStyle.DoubleQuoted to a particular property using WithAttributeOverride but this requires a class name and the model to be serialised is dynamic. This also requires listing every property to change (of which there are many). I would like to change the style for all multi-line string properties at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question, I've now worked out how to do this by deriving from the `ChainedEventEmitter` class and overriding `void Emit(ScalarEventInfo eventInfo, IEmitter emitter)`. See code sample below.

```cs
public class MultilineScalarFlowStyleEmitter : ChainedEventEmitter
{
    public MultilineScalarFlowStyleEmitter(IEventEmitter nextEmitter)
        : base(nextEmitter) { }

    public override void Emit(ScalarEventInfo eventInfo, IEmitter emitter)
    {

        if (typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(eventInfo.Source.Type))
        {
            string value = eventInfo.Source.Value as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                bool isMultiLine = value.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '\r', '\n', '\x85', '\x2028', '\x2029' }) >= 0;
                if (isMultiLine)
                    eventInfo = new ScalarEventInfo(eventInfo.Source)
                    {
                        Style = ScalarStyle.Literal
                    };
            }
        }

        nextEmitter.Emit(eventInfo, emitter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for using this with SerializerBuilder: `builder.WithEventEmitter(nextEmitter => new MultilineScalarFlowStyleEmitter(nextEmitter));`