# How to force YamlDotNet to use Folded Block Scalar for all multi-line strings

Tags: serialization, yaml, yamldotnet

With YamlDotNet I'm getting inconsistent serialization. I'm serializing with a basic serializer:

```
new YamlDotNet.Serialization.SerializerBuilder()
.DisableAliases()
.ConfigureDefaultValuesHandling(DefaultValuesHandling.OmitDefaults)
.Build()
.Serialize(target)
```

When I serialize a simple anonymous object it works more or less correctly, expanding multi-line strings with the [YAML Multiline Guide](https://yaml-multiline.info/). It has double line feeds, which seems like a bug similar to that reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58431796/647492), but is otherwise correct.

So if I serialize:

```
    new {
    A = 1,
    B = "Testing",
    Group1 = new {
        Field1 = "Test 1\r\n\"This\"",
        Field2 = "Test 2\r\n'That'"
    }
}.ToYaml()
```

I get just about what I expect (other than the double newlines):

```
A: 1
B: Testing
Group1:
  Field1: >-
    Test 1

    "This"
  Field2: >-
    Test 2

    'That'
```

So far so good. When I try to serialize a real object that looks like this in JSON:

```
    {
  "Parameters": {
    "CommitmentSpecIds": {
      "Choices": {
        "1060": "Location"
      }
    },
    "DisplayValue": {
      "Text": "LOC: {{Question.Schedule->LocationName}}"
    },
    "Tooltip": {
      "Text": "Staff: {{Question.Schedule->StaffName}}\nAppointment: {{Question.Schedule->ScheduleDate@d}}"
    }
  }
}
```

I end up with the lines being double-quoted if they have any newlines, just as they do in JSON.

```
Parameters:
  CommitmentSpecIds:
    Choices:
      1060: Location
  DisplayValue:
    Text: 'LOC: {{Question.Schedule->LocationName}}'
  Tooltip:
    Text: "Staff: {{Question.Schedule->StaffName}}\nAppointment: {{Question.Schedule->ScheduleDate@d}}"
```

I've searched a couple hours, but assume I'm missing something simple.

How do I force `Folded Block Scalar Style` for all strings with newlines.

Comment: Are you using Mustache in your Yaml?

Comment: Not really. The {{ }} are a sort of template language, but not specifically mustache.